# * if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{n}$ be divergent then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n u_{n}$ is convergent or divergent *

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{n}$ be divergent
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n u_{n}$ this series is divergent or convergent?
thanks in advance

Comment: If $u_n\geq 0$ $\forall n$ the it is surely divergent (since $nu_n\geq u_n$...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The series is divergent.

I will prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\,u_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ is also convergent.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\,(n\,u_n).
$$
The sequence $1/n$ is decrasing and converges to $0$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\,u_n$ converges, the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^nk\,u_k$ are bounded. By [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_criterion), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges.